# NodeJS use client certificate from Azure Key Vault in request

Tags: node.js, https, azure-keyvault, client-certificates

I'm trying to perform a `post` request to an API that requires client certificate authentication. The certificate was uploaded to an Azure Key Vault in `pfx` form.

I'm able to retrieve the certificate from the Key Vault using the npm modules `@azure/keyvault-certificates` or `@azure/keyvault-secrets` (ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/7647#issuecomment-594935307)

The problem is that I'm unsure on how to proceed from here. I'm using `axios` to perform the server-side request and I'm attaching the certificate in a custom `httpsAgent` like this:

```js
const { certPfx, passphrase, endpoint } = options
const headers = constructHeaders(options)

const axiosInst = axios.create({
    httpsAgent: new Agent({
        pfx: certPfx,
        // pfx: Buffer.from(certPfx) // Alternative using the `cer` property of the returned certificate
        passphrase // Set from env var (I've verified that this is correct)
    })
})

return axiosInst.post(endpoint, constructBody(), {
    headers
})
```

The `certPfx` variable is either a `Uint8Array` if retrieving the certificate through `keyvault-certificates` or a base64 string if using `keyvault-secrets`.

The problem is that no matter the combination I use I'm getting an error `Error: wrong tag` and failure once I try to post the request. I've tried with and without the passphrase as well as using the `cer` `Uint8Array` and the base64 version and nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have a small sample of using a client certificate from Azure Key Vault to make an https request using node/typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the correct way to encode the certificate is to use a base64 buffer and read the certificate as a secret (ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/7647#issuecomment-594935307)

So assuming you have a proper SecretClient and Key Vault with a certificate saved you can do this:

```js
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity"
import { SecretClient } from "@azure/keyvault-secrets"
import axios from "axios"

// omitted setup of some variables for clarity

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential()
const client = new SecretClient(vaultUrl, credential)
const secret = await client.getSecret(certName) // The secret name will be the same as the cert name
const certPfx = secret.value // assuming this is set.

const axiosResponse = await axios(endpoint, {
    data: constructBody(),
    headers,
    method: "POST",
    httpsAgent: new Agent({
        pfx: Buffer.from(certPfx, "base64"),
        passphrase: ""
    })
})
```